# error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). C++ Vscode

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

I have tried to run the file but got  *error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)*.

My program is given below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout<<"Hola Mundo!\n ";   
    return 0;
}
```

My file, which is named as 2, has the following files:

- .vscode
  ->launch.json
  ->tasks.json
- a.out
- saludo.cpp

tasks.json file

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: clang build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "args": [
            "-fcolor-diagnostics",
            "-fansi-escape-codes",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
```

}

Full Error message :

Executing task: C/C++: clang build active file

```
Starting build...
/usr/bin/clang -std=gnu++14 -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -g /Users/name/Desktop/cpp/2/saludo.cpp -o /Users/name/Desktop/cpp/2/saludo
ld: Undefined symbols:
  std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const, referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet[abi:v160006]<std::__1::ctype<char>>(std::__1::locale const&) in saludo-d23c3a.o
  std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const, referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>::widen[abi:v160006](char) const in saludo-d23c3a.o
  std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>::__init(unsigned long, char), referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>::basic_string[abi:v160006](unsigned long, char) in saludo-d23c3a.o
  std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>::~basic_string(), referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>> std::__1::__pad_and_output[abi:v160006]<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in saludo-d23c3a.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>> std::__1::__pad_and_output[abi:v160006]<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in saludo-d23c3a.o
  std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&), referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>& std::__1::__put_character_sequence[abi:v160006]<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, char const*, unsigned long) in saludo-d23c3a.o
  std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>::sentry::~sentry(), referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>& std::__1::__put_character_sequence[abi:v160006]<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, char const*, unsigned long) in saludo-d23c3a.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>& std::__1::__put_character_sequence[abi:v160006]<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, char const*, unsigned long) in saludo-d23c3a.o
  std::__1::cout, referenced from:
      _main in saludo-d23c3a.o
  std::__1::ctype<char>::id, referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet[abi:v160006]<std::__1::ctype<char>>(std::__1::locale const&) in saludo-d23c3a.o
  std::__1::locale::~locale(), referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>::widen[abi:v160006](char) const in saludo-d23c3a.o
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>::widen[abi:v160006](char) const in saludo-d23c3a.o
  std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow(), referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>& std::__1::__put_character_sequence[abi:v160006]<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, char const*, unsigned long) in saludo-d23c3a.o
  std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int), referenced from:
      std::__1::ios_base::setstate[abi:v160006](unsigned int) in saludo-d23c3a.o
  std::terminate(), referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in saludo-d23c3a.o
  ___cxa_begin_catch, referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>& std::__1::__put_character_sequence[abi:v160006]<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, char const*, unsigned long) in saludo-d23c3a.o
      ___clang_call_terminate in saludo-d23c3a.o
  ___cxa_end_catch, referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>& std::__1::__put_character_sequence[abi:v160006]<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, char const*, unsigned long) in saludo-d23c3a.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>& std::__1::__put_character_sequence[abi:v160006]<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, char const*, unsigned long) in saludo-d23c3a.o
  ___gxx_personality_v0, referenced from:
      /private/var/folders/6g/p9wrqvrx7gxcbprsxdzscjy00000gn/T/saludo-d23c3a.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 

 *  Executing task: C/C++: clang build active file
```

Comment: Nothing that you describe shows the reason for the linker error. Can you add the tasks.json and show the actual build command that was executed? Please add both as text not a picture of text.

Comment: VSCode is a very advanced, complex development tool that's designed for highly skilled, experienced developers who have a wide range of domain knowledge, like the JSON configuration syntax, and familiarity with obscure compiler flags and options. It is not meant to be used for people who are just starting out learning C++ and who do not have established development experience, those people will find other development environments, like VS community edition (Windows) or emacs+make (Linux, MacOS), easier to use.

Comment: My guess would be you're compiling with gcc rather than g++ to compile. Please show the full compiler output

Comment: Based on a quick Google search, here is a convenient website with which you can start C++ programming without having to install anything (not even VSCode) to your computer: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler . When I copy-paste your program there, it works. Another such website is https://cpp.sh/

Comment: Have you tried reading [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac) and follow it?

Comment: @drescherjm I have added json file

Comment: *linker command failed with exit code 1* is only last line of a bigger build output. Be kind to post the complete error message above the last line.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have added the full error message

Comment: Use clang++ for C++ code. It should have been mentioned in any C++ tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing this to close the question. Apparently  my tasks.json file is wrong. I have changed clang to clang++ and it worked. Thanks everybody for helping.